# Rule to send an email on node save printing a field value of a referenced node

Tags: 7, rules, emails

I am using Drupal 7, and the modules [References](http://www.drupal.org/project/references) and [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

I created two content types: A and B.

A has a field (A:b_nodes) which is multiple node references of B which has field (B:time).

How can I configure a rule so that when A is saved, an email will be sent with body text like the following:

```
here are the B nodes time data contained in A

B1 : 2 januari 2013
B2 : 5 may 2013
B3 : 15 august 2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **/admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/add** and create a rule. Then in rules action section under system category select **Send email**. Then you will be redirect to a new page, here you can define the subject,content,recipient of mail. By using **Replacement Patterns** you can add dynamic variable in to mail content.

Comment: I've done that. But the email only show B1 - B3 title. the time is empty...